# Flex RichTextEditor - Discard Ctrl+Y

Tags: apache-flex, air, keydown, rich-text-editor, undo-redo

I'm using RichTextEditor in my AIR desktop application, built with flex 3.6.

Since there's no undo/redo management, I'm trying to extend the component functionality.

I got a function I got a problem everytime <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> are pressed.

This what I actually do when a key is pressed.

```
<mx:RichTextEditor 
    id="myRTE"
    keyDown="onKeyDown(event);"
/>

....

public function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.charCode == 122)
    {
        // ctrl + z pressed!
        undo();
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.charCode == 121)
    {
        // ctrl + y pressed!
        redo();
    }
}
```

My problem is that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> output also a weird char in my RichTextEditor but i would like to discard it.

I tried to put a event.stopImmediatePropagation(); just after the redo(); but the weird char is appended to my RichTextEditor anyway.

I really don't know how get rid of that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    myRTE.textArea.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, textInput);
}

private function textInput(event:TextEvent):void {
    // <CTRL+V pressed
    if (event.text.length > 1)
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

RichTextEditor encapsulate and using TextArea. You can add event for TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT to prevent <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> event.

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan! I've just added event.preventDefault() after the redo();. It was enough to do what i needed!